# How to show every value in y-axis using Plotly Express?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-express

When I do:

```
fig = px.line(df, x="day", y="avg_spending")


fig.show()
```

It doesn't put values in y axis by 2 (0, 2, 4,...). I want it to be 1 by 1 (0,1,2,3,..). My maximum value of "avg_spending" in df is 17, so I would like there to be 1,2,3,...,17 on y axis. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the **dtick** parameter on the axis

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({"day":range(50),"avg_spending":np.random.randint(1,17,50)})

fig = px.line(df, x="day", y="avg_spending")
fig.update_layout(yaxis={"dtick":1},margin={"t":0,"b":0},height=500)
```

Comment: thanks, but they all cover each other. how to do it with keeping space between ticks?

Comment: updated - just give it more space ....

Comment: and is it possible to add 0 as a starting point of axis? cause I dint have one right now?

Comment: take a look at docs,  you can config a lot of things https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/xaxis/ `fig.update_layout(yaxis={"dtick":1,"range":[0,17]},margin={"t":0,"b":0},height=500)
` if you want to include zero in yaxis range

Comment: it may seem as if the default behavior with regard to axis ticks varies slightly between the `show()` and `write_html` methods